# Where does docker store local cache in Ubuntu?

Tags: docker, caching, containers

I want to save layer cache created by Docker during build in an external source. I will restore cache from the external source in the next build.

I don't want to use --cache-from and --cache-to options as it requires using different build driver other than default. I have to stick to using default docker driver.

I tried to research in which directory does docker save local cache, but could not find any useful information.

Any kind of help would be appreciated